# JBoss EAP 6 - How to deploy huge exploded folder

Tags: deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

We run JBoss 6 in standalone mode. We do have a folder (`content.war/`) in deployments that contains a symlink to a different folder (let's call it `docs`). Symlinking is enabled in jboss-web.xml with `<symbolic-linking-enabled>true</symbolic-linking-enabled>`. Our scenario is to use this to serve static files via this app context.

We do deploy the folder using `touch content.war.dodeploy`. It all works fine when the `docs` folder contains just few files. When the `docs` folder points to actual folder that has around **30GB** the deployment seems to be stuck (the folder is not deployed and no other deployment works afterwards).

**I believe that JBoss tries to somehow traverse or scan the whole folder. Is it possible to somehow disable this behaviour?**

Comment: Did you get a timeoutException during the deployment ? If yes, you can maybe increase the value of the `deployment-timeout` (default value is 600 seconds) in the subsystem `deployment-scanner`

Comment: The root of the problem would be the entire deployment needs to be scanned. You may want to look at static resources https://wildscribe.github.io/JBoss%20EAP/6.4/subsystem/web/configuration/static-resources/index.html

Comment: RE Nicolas - We didn't see any timeoutException in the server.log but I guess that the timeout setting would have to be unacceptably long (delaying the server restart too).

RE James - Is there any example how the web subsystem should be used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround seems to do the trick. I can deploy an empty exploded war folder and once it is deployed I create the symlink to the huge folder.

Disadvantage: When JBoss is restarted it gets stuck again. I'd need to remove the link and create it again after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use welcome-content that JBoss uses to serve static content. I can remove the original `welcome-content` folder and create a symlink to my folder instead.

```
ln ‐sv /home/mypath/my-static-content ${JBOSS_HOME}/welcome‐content
```

Disadvantage: This doesn't allow you to use any symlinks inside your folder or subfolders.